# Multiple same decorators in GeoServer WMS layer

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, wms

I have added decorator with scalebar on my Leaflet (WMS GeoServer layer), but I see many decorators, probably one for each subtile of map.
Map image:
[image]

WMS layer:

```
var t2mLayer = L.tileLayer.wms(WMSlink, {
    layers: ' stor:t2m',
    format: 'image/png',
    transparent: true,
    format_options: 'layout:test',
});
```

test.xml:

```
<layout>

    <decoration type="scaleline" affinity="bottom,left" offset="36,6"/>

</layout>
```

I believe this is due to GeoServer settings. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What is "decorator with scalebar"?

Comment: white rectangle on above image with 20 km/mi distance distance shown. Actually it is a type scaleline decoration.

Comment: Question is not about it's appearance, but the code that produces it. Where does it come from?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. It is in test.xml file. type='scaleline' is code for scaleline. It is a file in layouts folder of Geoserver which automatically reads it. File is afterwards referenced in format_options: 'layout:test', where it is assigned to WMS layer.

Comment: OK, so this is obviously Geoserver problem.

Comment: Well, I'd say it's a Geoserver *feature*. OP probably wants to check some Leaflet plugin for untiled WMS.

Answer (score 2):

You are using a **tiled** layer in leaflet, so it requests a small image for each tile as a **separate** WMS request. GeoServer returns the image including the decorator that you asked for. Each request is a completely separate operation for GeoServer (and in some cases it might be to a different machine) so you get a scale bar on each tile.

So this is working exactly as expected and as you asked for. If you only want a single scale bar then you should either ask for a single WMS image for your entire map or draw the scale bar in the client.